# Set the algorithm environment to normal spacing apart from other parts in the document

Tags: environments, algorithm2e

Throughout the document, I use \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} for the entire document. Now I want to set only the algorithm environment in \usepackage{algorithm2e} to the normal spacing, what should I do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\RestyleAlgo{ruled}
I want my main text to be baselinestretch 1.5. by using renewcommand{baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Triple Rapid}\label{alg:three}
%\KwData{Write here the required data}
%\KwResult{Write here the expected result}
 Initialization: A list of distinct integers $x = \{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$\;
  \eIf{$n\leq 1$}{
   Return $x$
   }{
   Set Pivot $p = x$\;
   Extract list of elements $x'$ less than $p$\;
   Extract list of elements $x''$ greater than $p$\;
   Return (\text{TripleRapid}($x'$), $p$, \text{TripleRapid}($x''$))\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

If I use `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}`, the algorithm will gives something like this

[image]

However, I want something that looks like this

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Can you please show a small example of code to play with?

Comment: @egreg I have editted the question, hope it is better!

Comment: Not really. A small (but compilable) piece of code should be here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than changing `\baselinestretch` after `\begin{document}` you should use `\linespread{1.5}` *before* it.

Anyway, I recommend using `setspace`, if you really need enlarged interline space and its `\onehalfspacing` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\RestyleAlgo{ruled}

\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithm}{%
  \singlespacing
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}%
}

\onehalfspacing
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8} % because \baselinestretch is 1.25

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Triple Rapid}\label{alg:three}
%\KwData{Write here the required data}
%\KwResult{Write here the expected result}
 Initialization: A list of distinct integers $x = \{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$\;
  \eIf{$n\leq 1$}{
   Return $x$
   }{
   Set Pivot $p = x$\;
   Extract list of elements $x'$ less than $p$\;
   Extract list of elements $x''$ greater than $p$\;
   Return $(\mathrm{TripleRapid}(x'), p, \mathrm{TripleRapid}(x''))$\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

The redefinitions of `\arraystretch` ensure that matrices will not be ruined by the enlarged `\baselinestretch`.

If you really want `1.5`, say `\setstretch{1.5}` and instead of `0.8` use `0.66667`.

[image]

Please, note the changes I made to the second “Return” line: you should have a single math formula.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed!